# Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x100028330)

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, cllocation

[image]

its Swift 4.0 .when application run on physical device its show this type of error which is not understandable i want to convert location Latitude and longitude into float

Comment: `!` means "crash here if nil`. What's the point of all of the optional chaining if you just force-unwrap it at the end?

Comment: i cant understand this whole because i m beginner

Comment: If you're a beginner, you might start by reading the sections of the language guide related to Optionals, Optional Binding, and Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals.